# Not able to add the plugin such as the lighthouse in my cypress project

Tags: javascript, testing, npm, automation, cypress

I have a project with the cypress automation. I am trying to add the plugin such as the cypress in my project but after changing my index.js in plugin folder.It shows me the error of

```
cy.lighthouse() is not a function
```

index.js file

```
const { lighthouse, pa11y, prepareAudit } = require("cypress-audit");
module.exports = (on, config) => {
  // `on` is used to hook into various events Cypress emits
  // `config` is the resolved Cypress config
};
```

can any one help on this issue.
Thanks!

Comment: Sharing your `plugin/index.js` and any other changes will greatly help your chances of getting help.

Comment: hey, I have use the command 
 
npm install --save-dev cypress-audit

then add this line in my index.js file from plugins>index.js

const { lighthouse, pa11y, prepareAudit } = require("cypress-audit");

I have edit my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at the docs, this should be the full `cypress/plugins/index.js`

**Cypress v9 - cypress/plugins/index.js**

```js
const { lighthouse, pa11y, prepareAudit } = require("cypress-audit");

module.exports = (on, config) => {
  on("before:browser:launch", (browser = {}, launchOptions) => {
    prepareAudit(launchOptions);
  });

  on("task", {
    lighthouse: lighthouse(), // calling the function is important
    pa11y: pa11y(), // calling the function is important
  });
};
```

But your error message "cy.lighthouse() is not a function" is caused by missing line in `cypress/support/index.js` which you also add

**Cypress v9 - cypress/support/index.js**

```js
import "cypress-audit/commands";
```

---

For latest Cypress

**Cypress v10 - cypress.config.js**

```js
const { defineConfig } = require('cypress')
const { lighthouse, pa11y, prepareAudit } = require("cypress-audit");

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:1234',
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {

    on("before:browser:launch", (browser = {}, launchOptions) => {
      prepareAudit(launchOptions);
    });

    on("task", {
      lighthouse: lighthouse(), // calling the function is important
      pa11y: pa11y(), // calling the function is important
    }); 
  },
})
```

**Cypress v10 - cypress/support/e2e.js**

```js
import "cypress-audit/commands";
```

Comment: Thanks a lot the code is running for now i am using the cypress 9.

Answer (score 0):

This code works fine for me:

```
  const { lighthouse, pa11y, prepareAudit } = require("cypress-audit");
    
    module.exports = (on, config) => {
      on("before:browser:launch", (browser = {}, launchOptions) => {
        prepareAudit(launchOptions);
      });
    
      on("task", {
        lighthouse: lighthouse(), // calling the function is important
        pa11y: pa11y(), // calling the function is important
      });
    };
```

Cypress v9 - `cypress/support/index.js`

```
import "cypress-audit/commands";
```